# Why was my question about Visual Studio Code closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: *[Can I use Visual Studio Code while everybody else use Visual Studio in the team (ASP.NET in particular)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65079666/can-i-use-vscode-while-every-body-else-use-visual-studio-in-the-team-asp-net-in)*

Why was this question closed as it's opinion based! I'm just asking if Visual Studio Code can cause a crash in normal Visual Studio projects! How is this opinion based?

The full text of the question follows:

> Does Visual Studio Code cause any issue or add any file to the solution created in Visual Studio?
>
> Can I use Visual Studio Code while everybody else use Visual Studio in the team (ASP.NET projects)?
>
> [visual-studio-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code)

Comment: Please note that your claim "I'm just asking if VsCode can cause a crash in normal visual studio projects!" is not supported by the question you linked from main. And it definitely asks "Can I use VS Code while everybody else use Visual Studio in the team" which can't be answered by strangers on the interwebs.

Comment: For the 2nd question, I think it's a question you should be discussing/asking with your teammates.

Comment: Vscode is basically an Code editor with  functions, so the answer to your second question, yes you can use it to edit the code, But as long the code doesn't has features that are only supported by professional or team edition you can also use the express edition

Comment: At any rate the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: The answer to a question like this is always yes. Yes you can. You can also use notepad if you want. That is not the question you should be asking; the relevant question is if you are going to be able to function within the team if you decide to go left while everyone else is going right. That's something you'd best ask them.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov this is a question to know if it can cause a crash in the solution files somehow and I'm really not asking about opinions. I expected someone how has experienced it or has knowledge how vscode workspace config file and vs solution files are being managed answer this question.

Answer (score 23):

We can't tell if it crashes for you, or if it behaves like you expect it to behave in your context.

There might be bugs, corner cases, setups, specific actions that cause problems in achieving a certain task but it is impossible to list them all for you and give a definitive answer.

You never have to ask: *Can I do X* on Stack Overflow. Just do X, take note of the steps, your setup and observe the result. If that isn't what you expect you can, after you've done research, formulate a question for the specific task you have trouble achieving with your tool used by programmers. The answer to that question will solve your specific problem.

Comment: "Can I do...?" "Yis".... What answer people expect us to give?

Comment: @Alvi15 I fear it's often "Can I do this?" -> "Yes, here is how: ...". Unfortunately, that doesn't work in many cases, as it's *possible* but there is a myriad of ways to go about it. There isn't The One Way To Do It To Rule Them All. As rene points out the correct approach is to identify *what* doesn't work for you and ask how to solve that. There are jokes about engineers answering literally but not usefully and...there is a basis for it. We often *cannot* answer otherwise. There are many unknowns around a situation and we want to give an answer that's as accurate as possible.

Comment: I was expecting someone who has knowledge about visual studio solution files and vscode config files answer this question, basically I just needed to know if there will be any conflict between this two tools. I'm not asking about a general opinion from someone who doesn't have technical knowledge or experience to know how to answer this question.

Comment: Basically, I expected if someone doesn't know the answer don't reply to it, not just closing it because they don't know the answer !

Comment: @user14615852 VS and VSCode both support *.sln files. Whether that works for all features that are in asp.net and the extremely well integrated support in VS is to be seen. As you didn't include which features you plan to use it  is impossible to say upfront if what you and your team tries to achieve will work. That is why I suggest: Try it and if anything of a feature fails ask about that. As stated your question is too broad.

Comment: @user14615852 when people cast a close vote it's not because they personally cannot answer but because the answer will depend on details that are missing from the question. Your question is exactly this - there is no real way of comprehensively answering what all permutations of working and non-working combination of features is between VS and VSCode. For some cases, there is nothing you need to do and stuff just works. In other cases, the features are largely incompatible unless you use external solutions like plugins to handle them. Others still will be anywhere on this spectrum.

Comment: @IanKemp and VLAZ what rene just said, is an answer, the reason i asked it because i didn't knew about unsupported features, if i knew it why would i asked it at the first place ! couldn't it be said on the ticket?! couldn't someone asked for more clarification on the ticket ?

IanKemp we are discussing a reason for closing a question, I really didn't expect a personal attack from you !